# Kendo Grid: Prevent datasource refreshing on grid filtering

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I got a grid displaying +- 4000 candidates. You can search and filter the grid by typing in a textbox. For each character typed there is a 1.5 second debounce before the grid refreshes/filters with the textbox content as a parameter.

On my local database this works like a charm. But on the live environment there is a big performance issue.

Each time the filter is applied, the Read action is called, all data is fetched and filtered. This means a new request to the server for every character typed. 
What I want to achieve is that when filtering, the filtering happens on the data inside the grid, instead of refreshing/reloading the whole datasource on every filter.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: The typical way of filtering data in a kendo grid is by the default filtering of the columns. I don't understand how do you use the filter textbox you are reffering to. Provide your code please in order to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This can be simply achieved by setting `serverFiltering` in `DataSource` to false.

[API Reference](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-serverFiltering)